# Decrease Spacing Between Headlines

Tags: css

Is there a way to decrease the space between two H1's i.e.,

## Happy Holidays!!!

## From Me

Normally I'm assuming there is a default amount of space between 2 h1's.

But is there a way to decrease the space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to decrease the space between those particular lines and not affect other headings, you can add an in-line style to the `<h1>` tags like this:

```
<h1 style="margin:0;">
```

If you want a small space, replace the 0 (Example: 5px, 10px).

Answer (score 0):

`<h1>` tags have default margins.

Write:

```
h1{margin:0;}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/LtZSd/)

Answer (score 0):

you need

```
h1{
  margin:0;
  line-height:1;
}
```

[proof](http://jsfiddle.net/7fAbp/1/)

**ps**:just play around with the buttons, and dont let it mix your mind that `line-height` has a numeric value in its css but `px` suffix can be used to animate with `jQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Note that the right solution is not to use two H1's, but rather a line break.

Try viewing this with default styling and you will see:

```
<H1>Happy Holidays!!<BR>
From Me</H1>

<H1>And All The Best in The New Year</H1>
```

There are margins around headings for a reason; you usually want to keep them.
In the case of one H1 followed by another, what you can do is make the CSS rule so that it applies just to that case. Use the `H1 + H1` selector to just give the second H1 a smaller `margin-top`.